# Custom ListView show only one record

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-sqlite

Hello my customlist view shows only one record. Everything is fine it shows multiple records in console but when ever i try to show the records in `ListView` it shows only last record its overriding first record, currently there are two records which are showing in my console but in `ListView` it shows only last record, I am searching for solution since yesterday , I have spend more then 6 hours to solve this problem.

**Cart_Adapter.java**

```
public class Cart_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<ProductBean> list;
    String abc;
    public Cart_Adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ProductBean> list) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
}
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v=view;
    if(v==null){

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cartxml,null);

    }
        TextView title=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView size=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.size);
        TextView color=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.color);
        Button remove=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        title.setText(list.get(i).getTitle());
        size.setText(list.get(i).getSize());
        color.setText(list.get(i).getColor());

    ArrayList<ImagesBean> aa =list.get(i).getImagesList();
    if(aa!=null){
    for(i=0; i<aa.size(); i++) {

        abc = String.valueOf(aa.get(i).getImgone());
        System.out.println("--testing" + abc);
    }

    }
    System.out.println("===="+abc);
    if(abc !=null ) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromString(abc));
        //  imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromString(list.get(i).getImagesList()));
    }else{}
    return v;
}

   private Bitmap getBitmapFromString(String encode){
        byte[]  b = Base64.decode(encode,Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0,b.length);
   }
}
```

class from where I am getting database record

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList=mydatabase.getpid(userid);
    System.out.println("--outside"+arrayList);
    for(int i =0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {

        String l = arrayList.get(i);
        final String ll = l.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "");
        System.out.println("--before loop" + ll);

        for (String s : ll.split(",")) {

            int pid = Integer.parseInt(s);
            myadapter = new Cart_Adapter(Cart.this, mydatabase.getproduct_details(pid));
            lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
            }

        }
```

**Activity_cart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.bhm.ishopping.Cart">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

    android:id="@+id/customlayout"
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="#39a423"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.617"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="320dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:text="Your Cart Detail"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="373dp"
    android:layout_height="411dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/customlayout" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Submit Your Order"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lv" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Cart.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="99dp"
    android:layout_height="87dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/remove"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:text="Ttile"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.456"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
    android:text="Color"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
    android:text="Size"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/size"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/remove"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/color"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/size"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/size"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/remove"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/color" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/remove"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/size"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:background="#5d8f37"
    android:text="X"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

console output show two records

```
enter code here System.out: ===pids1 System.out: ==database record[ProductBean{id='', title='ddd', color='dff', size='Select Size', type='Shart', cost='ddf', imagesList=null System.out: ===pids2 System.out: ==database record[ProductBean{id='', title='aa', color='aa', size='Select Size', type='Select Type', cost='aa', imagesList=null}]
```

Comment: `cartxml` show your layout file

Comment: i have added xml file of adapter and activity also please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `cartxml` hight to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

like below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**EDIT**

```
ArrayList<ProductBean> list= new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> arrayList=mydatabase.getpid(userid);
    System.out.println("--outside"+arrayList);
   myadapter = new Cart_Adapter(Cart.this, list);
    lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
    for(int i =0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {

        String l = arrayList.get(i);
        final String ll = l.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "");
        System.out.println("--before loop" + ll);

        for (String s : ll.split(",")) {

            int pid = Integer.parseInt(s);
            list.addAll(mydatabase.getproduct_details(pid));

            }

        }
      myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
```

Comment: i was did this bro let me try again

Comment: omg it works Thank uuuuuuuu so much  please tell me why we use addall ?

Comment: @BakhtiyarHussain happy to help you you can read ablout addall from here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29

Comment: @BakhtiyarHussain also from here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20E%3E)

Answer (score 2):

```
 for (String s : ll.split(",")) {

        int pid = Integer.parseInt(s);
        myadapter = new Cart_Adapter(Cart.this, mydatabase.getproduct_details(pid));
        lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
        }
```

You are setting adapter inside loop .Which is totally wrong . Put this code outside Loop .
And one more thing Its time to upgrade to [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) . Its easy and better implementation of ViewHolder Pattern .

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList=mydatabase.getpid(userid);
 ArrayList<String> dataList=new ArrayList();;
        for(int i =0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
            String l = arrayList.get(i);
            final String ll = l.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "");
            System.out.println("--before loop" + ll);
            for (String s : ll.split(",")) {
              // Do your stuff add data to list here
               dataList.add(stringToAdd);
            }
        }
        myadapter = new Cart_Adapter(Cart.this, dataList);
        lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

Do this way and if your dataset is not building properly then i thing you are using wrong dataset for your list . Or probably you need an ExpandableListView . Figure out the dataSet first currently which is 'ArrayList'.

Comment: if i dont put adapter inside loop then how i can get multiple records because pid has two records

Comment: Each time you call `setAdapter` on same ListView the previous one is override . Solution is Build  the list of records in loop and then set the adapter Outside loop.

Comment: bro i did this i have just put lv.setAdapter(myadapter) outside the loop but it still shows only last record

Comment: what is yourlist bro ? how i can populate multiple records outside the loop?

Comment: Thats what i said you need to figure out it cause i have no idea of your models. It should be Single list containing all data for listView. See the updated answer it shows how to build list . Although i do not have idea what exactly this list contains and why this split loop is, but it will give the idea . Thx

Comment: i am just passing pid to database tabel and it returns records, suppose there are two pids 1 and two it will populate first record using pid1 and pid2  without loop i cant get multiple records

Answer (score 1):

Print your list size in getCount(), to be sure if list is being sent inside. Check your item's layout_height, it should be wrap_content.

Comment: how to do this ?

Comment: Log your array list size - 'Log.d('TAG',"size - "+ list.size())' in getCount() method. First view in your layout 'R.layout.cartxml' should have height 'wrap_content'.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting adapter each items in loop.

```
for (String s : ll.split(",")) {

            int pid = Integer.parseInt(s);
            myadapter = new Cart_Adapter(Cart.this, mydatabase.getproduct_details(pid));
            lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
            }

        }
```

so it will take last pid from the iteration and will fetch product details which you are setting in card adapter.

**Wrong part is:** you are calling setAdapter() with each iteration in the loop

**Solution:**
Collect the list of records in loop, you can keep adding product details in the array list and then set the final list outside loop in the adapter.

Comment: now i am calling lv.setAdapter(myadapter); outside the loop but still shows only one record

Comment: show me your PID records and structure, would be able to help you out quickly!

Comment: i have added console output

Answer (score 1):

Check your `cartxml` layout file. The root `RelativeLayout` height will be `wrap_content` otherwise it will take all the available space for a single item. Use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for `RelativeLayoutin` in your `cartxml`